# Are there any use cases relying on integer representation of two allocations being different in C?

Tags: c, pointers, standards, low-level

For example, consider the following C code snippet:

```
void *p = malloc(1);
void *q = malloc(1);

bool question = (uintptr_t) p == (uintptr_t) q;
```

I expect everyone expects `question` be always false.  (Surprisingly, the C11 standard does not require it, though.  The only restriction on `uintptr_t` is e.g. `((void *) ((uintptr_t) p)) == p`.  See 7.20.1.4 of the C11 standard for details.)

My question is: is there any realistic use case that **actually** relies on the guarantee that `question` be false, or more generally, the integer representations of two allocations be different?

Comment: It is quite common to use a `uintptr_t` as a "handle" to pass around and expect that you can cast it back to the original pointer type, dereference it, and get back what you originally pointed to. (I'm pretty sure casting a pointer to a `uintptr_t` and then casting it back to its original type must preserve its value.)

Comment: C 2011 requires the comparison be false. First, in draft N1570, clause 6.5.9, paragraph 6, states “Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.”…

Comment: … And, since it must be possible to convert a pointer to `uintptr_t` and back, the two `uintptr_t` values cannot be equal, because then they would not convert back to different pointers.

Comment: 7.18.1.4 of C11 is not related to this

Comment: @EricPostpischil question says 7.18.1.4, and you should write your comments into an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  It's 7.20.1.4, and I edited the question.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: My comments do not answer the question. The question is “is there any realistic program that actually relies on the guarantee…”. My comments point out the question is flawed.

Comment: Ok then we close this as Request for off-site resource :D

Comment: @EricPostpischil In my understanding, `i == j` doesn't necessarily mean `(char *) i == (char *) j` in the C11 standard.  The standard deliberately distinguishes the equality comparision (`i == j`) and value identity (`i` equals to `j`, or `i` can be replaced with `j` and vice verca).  For example, 7.20.1.4 doesn't say `((char *) ((uintptr_t) p))` can be replaced with `p`; it just says `((char *) ((uintptr_t) p)) == p`.

Comment: @JeehoonKang so which one do you want to ask?! do you want to ask for list of programs that rely on this (which is off-topic) or whether it is true that...

Comment: @JeehoonKang: You cannot have value identity without having identity of the pointers that result from converting the value. If some `uintptr_t x` compares equal to some `uintptr_t y`, then they have the same value in the C model. There is no additional information. The compared values are not even lvalues with some associated storage that might hide additional bits (before comparison in `x == y`, if `x` or `y` is an lvalue, it is converted to a value).There is no way for this one value to convert to pointers to two different objects.

Comment: “is there any realistic program that actually relies on the guarantee” sure.  There are legacy libraries that only provide a user parameter of type 'int' when setting up callbacks, instead of the more sane 'void*'.  Passing a pointer in as an int and casting it back in the callback is common, and unique pointers sent in must come back as the same, unique pointers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I just wanted to know whether there is a realistic use case, not the list of programs (edited the question).  Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: Your title says "integer representation of two allocations should differ in C?" and  in the body you ask for a use case?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Also edited the title.

Comment: Detail `(uintptr_t)` cast is specified for converting `void *`.  `p, q` are not `void*`

Comment: `uintptr_t` isn't rigorously specified but the intent is very clear, personally I am comfortable relying on compilers doing what is intended

Answer (score 3):

The question is flawed. First, consider this code (where we suppose that `malloc` does not return null):

```
void *p = malloc(1);
void *q = malloc(1);

bool question = (uintptr_t) p == (uintptr_t) q;
```

Per the C 2011 standard’s specification of `uintptr_t`, if we do:

```
void *p1 = (void *) (uintptr_t) p;
void *q1 = (void *) (uintptr_t) q;
```

Then `p1` must compare equal to `p`, and `q1` must compare equal to `q`. And, per the standard’s specification of the `==` operator, `p1` and `q1` must not compare equal to each other, since they are, respectively, equal to `p` and to `q`, and hence are pointers to different objects.

Because `(void *) (uintptr_t) p` and `(void *) (uintptr_t) q` produce different values, `(uintptr_t) p` and `(uintptr_t) q` must be different values. (This is because the conversion to `void *` is a mathematical function within the C model. Every time it is given a specific value, within the rules of C, it produces a result that is effectively the same, within the rules of C.) Therefore `(uintptr_t) p` is not equal to `(uintptr_t) q`.

Now consider this code, where we change `void *` to `char *`:

```
char *p = malloc(1);
char *q = malloc(1);

bool question = (uintptr_t) p == (uintptr_t) q;
```

The specification of `uintptr_t` is silent about conversions from `char *`. Obviously, these pointers to `char *` can be converted to `void *`. However, I do not see that the standard requires that a conversion from `char *` to `uintptr_t` must implicitly insert a conversion to `void *` or act as if it did. So I suppose this is technically undefined by the standard. But I doubt you will find any C implementation in which this differs from the `void *` version, except one constructed specifically to violate this.

Nonetheless, effectively every programmer that uses `uintptr_t` expects the result to fully identify the original pointer (it contains all the information to convert back to the original pointer), and hence they expect the `uintptr_t` result to differ from that of all different pointers.

As for one specific example, the Accelerate framework in macOS expects the result of converting different pointers to `uintptr_t` to produce different results, and I am sure many other parts of macOS do too.

Comment: `malloc` can return `NULL` both times :P.  Maybe `void *p = &arr[0], q = &arr[1]` would be a better example.  Nice answer, but maybe worth pointing out this extra assumption that the question makes.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks, I have added a supposition that `malloc` does not return 0. Were I writing the question anew, I would use the addresses of objects as you suggest, but I want to remain close to the OP’s question.

Comment: "Because (void *) (uintptr_t) p and (void *) (uintptr_t) q produce different values, (uintptr_t) p and (uintptr_t) q must be different values."  In my understanding of C11, it isn't.  Suppose `p0` and `q` are void pointers that points to adjacent objects of both size 1, and `p = p0 + 1`.  Then `(uintptr_t) p == (uintptr_t) q` should hold.  Since both `p` and `q` are valid pointers (off-by-one pointers are valid), `p == (void *) (uintptr_t) p` and `q == (void *) (uintptr_t) q`.  But `p` and `q` are different: `*(char*)q` may be a valid access while `*(char*)p` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeehoonKang: When `p` points to one past the end of an array (including a single object treated as an array for pointer arithmetic), it may compare equal to `q`. However, then `p` is not a pointer to an object. It is just a value that is treated as a specially in pointer rules. If `p` and `q` **are both pointers to objects** and point to different objects, then they are unequal, and the results of converting them to `uintptr_t` are unequal. The C rules guarantee pointers to different objects are different. They do not guarantee a pointer to one past an object differs from other pointers.

Comment: @JeehoonKang: In other words, the rules for “one past a pointer to the end of an array” are special and are not applicable to pointers to actual objects. Your question asks about two pointers to separately allocated objects, not about pointers that have been manipulated by arithmetic.

Comment: @JeehoonKang: If you ask the question “Are valid non-null pointers `p` and `q`, which are not pointers to the same object, necessarily different?” then the answer is no, because one could be a pointer to one past the last element of an array and the other could be a pointer to the object just beyond the array. But if you ask the question “Are valid non-null pointers `p` and `q`, which are pointers to different objects, necessarily different?” then the answer is yes, because pointers to different objects must be different.

Comment: "every programmer that uses `uintptr_t` expects the result to fully identify the original pointer`' perhaps that is very common, yet the round trip only makes an equivalent pointer, not necessarily  the original one with the same bit-pattern.  So some information is lost - perhaps non-critical information.

Comment: @chux: Not perhaps non-critical information; definitely. The result of the round trip must serve identically to the original pointer. Inside the C model, it must have the same value and operation as the original. Whether it has all the same bits in its object representation is irrelevant in the same way it is irrelevant whether any objects with padding bits have different values in those padding bits. We call two integers equal if they compare equal, even if the two integer objects compared have different values in their padding bits. Any hidden extra “stuff” is simply irrelevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Even without padding bits: +0.0 and -0.0 (or the archaic `int` -0 +0) have the same value yet contain a difference that is important in some contexts.  A pointers and its round-tripped pointer cousin also compare equally yet may have a non-padding bit pattern difference.  Importantly, these 2 pointers must equally, yet their `uintptr_t` castings need not compare equally.

Comment: @chux: I wrote of integer and pointer values. Floating-point values have different semantics.

Comment: If you want an integer example of what @chux is talking about, consider x86 real-mode segmentation.  A linear address is `seg<<4 + offset`, so there are many redundant representations for the same address. An ISO C implementation (without forcing the programmer to deal with `near` vs. `far` pointers / calls, unlike real implementations on x86-16) would presumably use 32-bit pointers in `seg:offset` representation, but conversion to `uintptr_t` could linearize it to a 20-bit address (e.g. stored in a 3-byte type).  This conversion is also probably required as part of regular pointer comparison.

Comment: Yeah, if you do `&a[1234]` somewhere, you want that to compare equal to what some other function gets from calculating backwards after you pass it `&a[65536]` (which definitely requires using a different segment register value)).  Unless you always "canonicalize" by using the lowest segment register value possible at function-call boundaries or other places where you aren't taking advantage of the as-if rule...